# Fallo al enviar los datos por post mediante jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo un botón que genera y elimina campos dinámicos, el límite lo tengo en 4, genera 4 campos dinámicos únicamente. Quiero guardar la información de texto que introduce el usuario para enviarla por post mediante jQuery. El fallo con el que quiero que me ayudéis es, que no se envía la información, porque al imprimirlo me dice que el `array` es `null`.

Quiero recibir los datos que ha insertado el usuario en otro fichero PHP para hacer una consulta.

El jQuery recoge los valores de los campos almacenándolos en un `array` para luego pasarlos por post, bueno esa es mi idea.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 1;
        // cuando cliquemos en el boton + se ejecutara la funcion que añade un nuevo campo
        $('#add').click(function() {
            // condicion que puede crear hasta un maximo de 4 campos 
            if (i >= 5) return
            i++;
            var crearTablas = $(
                '<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
                '<td>' +
                '<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Nombre Jugador" class="form-control name_list"  maxlength="100"/>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>' +
                '</td>' +
                ' </tr>');
            $('#dynamic_field').append(crearTablas);
        });
        // creamos la funcion eliminar el boton que consiste en cuando hagamos click en el boton este elimine el campo 
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
            // guardamos el identificador del boton en la variable
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            // eliminamos la fila por medio del identificador y el campo por medio de la variable que contiene el campo, y llamamos a la funcion remove que lo elimina
            $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
            // luego ponemos el contador a 1 para resetear el contador
            i = 1;
        });
        $('#submit').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "procesoInsertar.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: $('#insertarJugadores').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#insertarJugadores')[0].reset();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>


<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#misModales">
        Reservar
    </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="misModales" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="abrirContenido" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container">
            <form action="" role="form" method="POST">
              <div class="conf-content row" id="step-1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3>Insertar Jugadores</h3>
                  <div class="containerP1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <form name="insertarJugadores" id="insertarJugadores">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                          <table class="table" id="dynamic_field">
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Pulse en el + para introducir jugadores" class="form-control name_list input-group-lg" />
                              </td>
                              <!-- boton que añade un nuevo campo para introducir valores -->
                              <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Reservar</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer btnFooter d-flex justify-content-between">
          <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-md pull-left disabled-control" type="button" id="previous">Anterior</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success nextBtn btn-md pull-right" id="next" type="button">Siguiente</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-md close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- div.btnCaja>div.btnCaja-fila>div.btnCaja-step>a[href="#caja-1"][type="button"].start-class>p{Insertar jugadores} -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Convierte el arreglo a json antes de pasarlo dentro de la sentencia del ajax, creo que eso es todo.

Comment: Como seria?.. porque jquery voy limitado xD

Comment: Es decir, no lo harías en el jquery, lo harías por fuera con js y después al jquery en la petición le vas a pasar esa variable ya convertida en json, por ejemplo, creas una variable de nombre arreglo que será = a esto $('#insertarJugadores') que supongo que es el valor de tu arreglo, te creas otra variable de nombre json y conviertes tu arreglo de esta manera var json = JSON.stringify(array); y luego en el data del ajax en jquery pasas esa variable json.

Comment: me parece que es más en esta parte `data: $('#insertarJugadores').serialize(),` si estas serializando pero, estas mandando el valor del campo completo no el `val()` del mismo.

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes un `form` dentro de **otro** `form`? ¿Qué muestra en la consola un `console.log($('#insertarJugadores').serialize());`? ¿Estás llenando tu formulario realmente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no los va a pasar, `$('#insertarJugadores').serialize()` esto te los saca por `name`

aunque la idea es que te devuelva `{name: ["asd","ads","sdf"]}`, lo que esta intentando darle es `{name:["as"], name:["ada"]}` y psno puedes tener 2 `attr` con el mismo nombre,

```
var crearTablas = $(
                '<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
                '<td>' +
                '<input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Nombre Jugador" class="form-control name_list"  maxlength="100"/>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                '<button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>' +
                '</td>' +
                ' </tr>');
            $('#dynamic_field').append(crearTablas);
```

en lugar de hacer eso, mejor guardales en un lista y trabajas con esa,

```
let names = [];

function writed(event, pos){
    name[pos]=event.target.value;
}

<input type="text" name="name[]" onchange="writed(event, "+i+")" placeholder="Nombre Jugador" class="form-control name_list"  maxlength="100"/>

// names será la lista que recorras en el modal y será la que le pases el el `post`
```

Comment: muchas gracias los dos ejemplos este y el siguiente me han servido, teneís razon habían dos form xDD

Answer (score 0):

primero creo que tienes varios puntos que arreglar en tu codigo:

- html: porque tienes dos `form`?, solo deberías ocupar uno y ese es el que llevaria la loica del metodo `POST`.
- no muestras tu `php`, tambien es importante para saber como es que estas recibiendo los datos desde tu `.ajax()`.
- en cuestion de diseño la verdad me costo un poco de trabajo enterder el boton para agregar creo que deberias poner un boton indpendiente y si el usuario quiere agregar uno juagador mas pues lo pulsa, pero bueno esto dependera de ti completamente, solo es una sugerencia.

En base a esto formule la respuesta:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  // cuando cliquemos en el boton + se ejecutara la funcion que añade un nuevo campo
  $('#add').click(function() {
      // condicion que puede crear hasta un maximo de 4 campos 
      if (i >= 5) return
      i++;
      var crearTablas = $(
          '<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
          '<td>' +
          '<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Jugador" class="form-control name_list"  maxlength="100"/>' +
          '</td>' +
          '<td>' +
          '<button type="button" name="remove" id="' + i + '" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button>' +
          '</td>' +
          ' </tr>');
      $('#dynamic_field').append(crearTablas);
  });
  // creamos la funcion eliminar el boton que consiste en cuando hagamos click en el boton este elimine el campo 
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
      // guardamos el identificador del boton en la variable
      var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
      // eliminamos la fila por medio del identificador y el campo por medio de la variable que contiene el campo, y llamamos a la funcion remove que lo elimina
      $('#row' + button_id + '').remove();
      // luego ponemos el contador a 1 para resetear el contador
      i = 1;
  });
  $('#submit').click(function(e) {

      // guardamos el valor de los campos en una variable
      //var name = $('#nombresJugadores').val();
      //agregue el form en una variable aunque funcionaria directamente en el data:
      var name = $('form').serialize();
    //detengo el proceso de envio un poco para ver los datos...
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url : 'procesoInsertar.php',
      method: "POST",
      data: name,
      success: function(data) {
        //alert(data);
        // aca veras los datos del formulario
        console.log( data );
        //$('#insertarJugadores')[0].reset();

        
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-timepicker/0.5.2/js/bootstrap-timepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>


<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#misModales">
        Reservar
    </button>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="misModales" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="abrirContenido" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container">
            <!--modifique tu primero form para que no haga nada-->
            <form role="form">
              <div class="conf-content row" id="step-1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <h3>Insertar Jugadores</h3>
                  <div class="containerP1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <!--En mi opinion este es el importante
                        aca agrego el metodo post
                      -->
                      <form method="POST" name="insertarJugadores" id="insertarJugadores">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                          <table class="table" id="dynamic_field">
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <!--cambie el name-->
                                <input id="nombresJugadores" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Pulse en el + para introducir jugadores" class="form-control name_list input-group-lg" />
                              </td>
                              <!-- boton que añade un nuevo campo para introducir valores -->
                              <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                          <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Reservar</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer btnFooter d-flex justify-content-between">
          <button class="btn btn-primary prevBtn btn-md pull-left disabled-control" type="button" id="previous">Anterior</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success nextBtn btn-md pull-right" id="next" type="button">Siguiente</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-md close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- div.btnCaja>div.btnCaja-fila>div.btnCaja-step>a[href="#caja-1"][type="button"].start-class>p{Insertar jugadores} -->
</body>
</html>
```

**OJO**, falta el php el cual solo lo tengo así:

```
<?php
/*para que veas la respuesta en tu data, en este caso tu console.log();*/
$recibe = $_POST['nombre'];
print_r($recibe);
?>
```

Saludos..

Comment: vale, pero me sale localhost dice y el código completo como string, yo quiero que se me oculta el primer modal de insertar y luego al pulsar en el botón reservar me vaya a otro modal que muestre la información insertada